# Does the SIM800L works in the US?

Tags: arduino-nano, gsm, communication

I want to know if the SIM800L works on US soil? I can´t get it to work on the H2O network! Does it work wit ATT or I only need the APN settings? If so what are the commands for data connection and configuration? Does the SIM800C works then?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to post an update in April 2021 on the status of this question.

The SIM800L will work in the US, but T-Mobile is the only carrier that it can interface with. [AT&T shut down its compatible towers in 2017. T-mobile will shut down its 2G network at the end of 2022](https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/02/05/t-mobile-3g-shutdown-reportedly-delayed-until-2022/).

So, the SIM800L is only good for another year and a half. Maybe you're better off finding a different module!

Answer (score 2):

Both SIM800C and SIM800L (you mention both modules in your question) are compatible with the US GSM networks. It is not possible for me to tell if H2O or AT&T have GSM coverage whereever you are trying to use the module. AT&T is planning to shut down their GSM network by the end of 2016. If you issue the `AT+COPS=?` command, the module will list all available networks at your location.

Documentation on the commands required to handle voice calls, SMS or internet connections can be found in the ['SIM800 Series AT Command 
Manual'](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/sim800_series_at_command_manual_v1.01.pdf).

Comment: Is that so... Then I should be moving to CDMA? or is there another network available? What chip could be useful? I´m planning to deploy this in a long term! Btw I did search for all available networks but none of them appeared and the signal was low or none existent! Why? No GSM/GPRS? I activated both

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why don't you simply do a network search with a regular cell phone? It will list which operators and which network types are available where you are. There are plenty of cellular modems for 3G and 4G networks as well, but they are quite a bit more expensive than the GSM modules.

Comment: Well there are plenty of networks around and I can confirm that H2O use AT&T network towers and the GSM network is present on all carriers. I saw that GPRS with 3g is available too but to my understanding it´s part of the GSM network, right? 

I saw different types of connections around the web... Do I need to use the reset pin? And what is the DTR pin? I got a battery at 3.7v with 2000mA connected so there is no problem with the ESD function of the chip

Comment: Does the SIM800L supports 3g? I mean from what I saw it does support 3g

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know 2G and 3G is still around however ATT and Verizon are not taking on anymore subscribers for 2G and 3G. However you might still could use a 3rd party such as ting.